# Kivy (Python 2.7) - How to load data on load of program

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I want to run a function to load data from external files when my Kivy application starts up. I am currently using a button to run the function because that seems to be the only way to accomplish my goal. If anyone has a better approach to this problem, your input would be greatly appreciated. Cheers! =)

Comment: Put the code inside  `__init__()` method of your class where the widget values you want to update are  or inside  `buid` method of `App` subclass.

Answer (score 2):

There are some solutions for this

You can bind the function to `on_parent` which occurs when your widget is added

or You can schedule your function with [Kivy Clock](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiH4ez_h-HXAhWKZ1AKHed5DoMQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkivy.org%2Fdocs%2Fapi-kivy.clock.html&usg=AOvVaw0NDC9h_m1xK0JeFrnernSr)